# Black screen displays When a the install4j installer is clicked

Tags: java, installation, install4j

I am using install4j version 6 to create setup for my Java GUI application
I have compile my project with jdk 7 and also bundled jre7. I have been doing this over the time and it work seamlessly. I have just tried to do this with a new project and as i create the installer, when clicked a black screen displays please help me see this screenshot.

Any help please, to me i can not figure out the cause of this.
[black screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pyifs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "black screen" is a console window.

On the Installer->Screens & Actions step, select the installer and deselect the "Windows console executable" property, you probably have selected this accidentally.

Comment: Thanks a lot the problem is solved just as you directed.